# Why do only open cubes shrink regularly?

Tags: measure-theory

$\textbf{DEFN}$ A collection of sets $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ is said to shrink regularly to $\overline x$, if there is a constant $c>0$, such that for each $U_{\alpha}$ there is a ball $B$ with

$\overline x \in B$, $U_{\alpha} \subset B$, and $m(U_{\alpha}) \ge cm(B)$.

where $\overline x$ is a point of Lebesgue density.

The book goes on to simply state that the set of all open cubes containing $\overline x$ shrink regularly to $\overline x$.

No proof of this statement is given (and I am not sure how to prove this and this is probably why I am asking the question).

Why do closed cubes not shrink regularly? I can't really see any intuition behind why this wouldn't be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that open cubes shrink regularly, suppose we have a cube $K$ of side length $s$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $m(K) = s^n$. Consider the smallest ball $B$ with the same center as $K$ containing $K$, i.e. $K$ is a cube inscribed in $B$; say they're centered at $0$, and $K$ is oriented with edges parallel to the appropriate axes. Then the corner of $K$ is at $(s/2,s/2,\ldots,s/2)$, so the radius of $B$ is given by $r = \sqrt{ns^2/4} = \sqrt{n}s/2$. So the volume of $B$ is given by $m(B) = C(n)r^n = C(n)n^{n/2}4^{-n}s^n = C(n)s^n$, where I've absorbed all of the constants depending only on $n$. But $s^n$ is the volume of $K$, so we have shown:
$$
m(K) = C(n)m(B),
$$
where $C(n)$ is a constant depending only on the dimension $n$. Now it's clear that the open cubes shrink regularly.

Nothing in the above used that $K$ is open, so the closed cubes also shrink regularly; the statement in your book doesn't preclude it.